# :conditions => "LIKE ___%" syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following gives an error: `ArgumentError: malformed format string - %'`:

```
 named_scope :sales, :conditions => ["rolename LIKE 'salesteam%'"]
```

The following is OK:

```
 named_scope :sales, :conditions => ["rolename LIKE 'salesteam%%'"]
```

I am wondering where I can find the documentation for the `%%` (double %) syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this? named_scope :sales, :conditions => ["rolename LIKE ?", 'salesteam%']

Comment: @Syed Aslam, you are right. Please put it in the answer and so I can credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
named_scope :sales, :conditions => ["rolename LIKE ?", 'salesteam%']
```